# Whats the difference of NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute and uiCulture in a asp.net mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created an asp.net MVC4 web project which must be available in more than one language.

I want to set the default language for this web project.
After some research, it seems the default language can be set in two places.

**NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute in AssemblyInfo**

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute("en")]
```

From msdn: [Informs the resource manager of an app's default culture. This class cannot be inherited.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.neutralresourceslanguageattribute.aspx)

**globalization uiCultur in web.config**

```
  <system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="en"/>
```

From mdsn: [Specifies the default culture for processing locale-dependent resource searches. For valid culture strings, see System.Globalization.CultureInfo Class.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

Now my questions:

What is the correct way to set the default language in a web project(NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute or globalization uiCultur) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example resource files

- Stuff.resx (contains english, is the default resources file)
- Stuff.de.resx (contains german)
- Stuff.fr.resx (contains french)

Now in web.config use

```
<globalization 
    enableClientBasedCulture="true" 
    uiCulture="auto:en" 
    culture="auto:en" />
```

This ("auto") will let the browser settings decide (german browsers gets the german resources, etc)

**However** (in the above example) if a Swedish browser comes it will default to **en** as there is no **se** (swedish) resource file and the fallback english ("auto: **en** ") uiCulture will be used.

So... then:

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute("en")]
```

lets the application now that english requests go direct to the default.resx with no other lookup for **en** resx first.

Also **if an english** browser is requesting it should go directly to the default resource file without trying something else first. So the NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute setting comes in play also here. The app knows to go to the default resx directly.

Comment: After some more testing, this seems to be the best answer. NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute is about assembly probing where web.config uiCulture only sets the default language.

Comment: I have a follow up question: in which assembly should it be specified? The executing assembly, or the assembly holding the resource files?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) article the important setting(s) for an Asp.Net web application are in the web.config in the "globalization" element. The article suggests setting both the culture and the uiCulture as a best practice. For example:

```
<globalization uiCulture="es" culture="es-MX" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute` is ONE way to let the application's resource manager know the default culture and resource location of your app. This attribute can be used for any type of .NET app: desktop, web, win8, wcf, etc.

The `globalization` attribute is another way to let your web application know what the default culture for your app is.

Note then that they key difference is that the `globalization` attribute only works for web apps and does not allow you to specify a different location for resources.

Recommendation: For a web project, I'd use the config attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The NeutralResourcesLanguage attribute informs the ResourceManager of the language that was used to display the resources of the neutral culture for an assembly. When it looks up resources in the same culture as the neutral resources language, the ResourceManager automatically uses the resources that are located in the main assembly.

It does this instead of searching for a satellite assembly that has the current user interface culture for the current thread. **NeutralResourcesLanguage attribute  improves lookup performance for the first resource that you load and can reduce your working set.**

from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/bb385967.aspx